# Get image from database and link it to its features or news etc in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, database

i have get the value from database, display it has a image and make it link. so I eant that when user click on the different image he get the result from the query related to the image.. I hope i make everyone understand

```
<?php
//connected to mysql
$image=$row['image'];
echo "<td><a href="feature.php"><img  src=images/".$image.".jpg width='250px' height='250px' /></td>";
?>
```

how can when user click image it get `$image` variable so, it can be used in sql in other page. the database many different images.

Comment: Use single quotes around `"feature.php"` (like `'feature.php'`) or the PHP interpreter will throw an error.

Comment: is this what you want? `href="feature.php?image=image123.JPG"`

Comment: Why are `javascript` and `ajax` tagged?

Answer (score 0):

Added the quotes into the tag,

```
  echo "<td><a href='feature.php'><img  src='images/".$image.".jpg' width='250px' height='250px' /></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass information to the feature.php page for example with a GET parameter:

```
<?php
        //connected to mysql
        $image=$row['image'];
        $imageRelatedInfoForSql = $image; // maybe $row['sql'] ???
        echo '<td><a href="feature.php?infoSql='.$imageRelatedInfoForSql.'"><img  src=images/'.$image.'.jpg width="250px" height="250px" /></td>';
?>
```

Doing so then in feature.php the passed information is available as:

```
<?php
    $infoForSql = $_GET['infoSql'];
    // use $infoForSql for your SQL query
?>
```

Please remember that some characters must be escaped when using them in an URL.

Comment: Thank u very much. . I understand You . :) .it really help me. I am very new to php so,I not good at it now. Tyhank u bro :)

Comment: I am happy that i could help you and i will also be happy if you could honor the help with an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

And in the same page you just make a code saying:

```
if(isset($_GET['img'])){
     $img = $_GET['img'];
     if(existsInDB($img)){
        echo 'now you do what you wish'

    }else{
          echo'the img doesnt exists, how do u like to handle this?';
    }

}else{

echo "<td><a href="feature.php?img=".$image.""><img  src=images/".$image.".jpg width='250px' height='250px' /></td>";

}
```